# Download GitHub Source code

Tags: c#, json, nuget-package-restore

I have this problem, I think I've downloaded already the source code from github.

https://github.com/Jessecar96/SteamDesktopAuthenticator

But the thing is, there's some error when I open the source code. Its something about "Json Newton" ? How can I open that one, I'm quite new to c# and its my first time to encounter with Json, need your help. Thanks

Comment: normally, when you open the project, visual studio will restore missing references. You will be prompted by this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Visual Studio > Tools menu > Nuget Package Manage > Manage Nuget Packages for Solution > look up **JSON** by James Newton-King and install it.

Comment: I've tried your method and it seems to work now, this really works like a charm. Really thankful for this, thank you. Been looking for a solution for ages, this really helps me. Thank you!

Comment: Cool, next to each answer is a holo tick box. Marking answers as correct gives you a couple of points and lets everyone know your question is answered

Comment: What you mean by the "holo tick box" thing?

Comment: Oh you already accepted this answer, sorry I didn't see that before, cheers

Answer (score 1):

The repo has a submodule and a reference into a project in the submodule in the parent solution. The standard project restore does not play well in this scenario. Packages are downloaded relative to the solution open in VS but the reference paths are relative to a solution in the submodule. The easiest way is going to be to build the submodule solution first.

If you haven't initialized the submodules (this doesn't happen by default unless you use --recurse when cloning), then go into the project folder and run

```
git submodule update --init
```

After that open lib\SteamAuth\SteamAuth.sln and build. Then go back to the Steam Desktop Authenticator solution and rebuild that.

Comment: but i tried opening it, and it does restore the missing packages

Comment: @Desperado Indeed they are restored but they go to the wrong place, so the reference cannot be found by the project's reference hint path.

Comment: yes you are correct, there are many errors when i build the code, give me dota 2 immortal sets then :P

Answer (score 0):

`Newtonsoft.Json` is a package that provides JSON serialization functionality. It appears that the project has it as a dependency (see `packages.config`). You may need to set your project to restore packages on builds.

(maybe a helpful article on this: http://blog.davidebbo.com/2014/01/the-right-way-to-restore-nuget-packages.html)